# Change banner depending on country

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, geolocation, detect

I want to show india.jpg if country is India and show srilanka.jpg is country is Srilanka.

**This detects my country**

```
alert("Your location is: " + geoplugin_countryName() + ", " + geoplugin_region() + ", " + geoplugin_city());
```

Geoloaction code of India : 22.512557, 80.076350
Geoloaction code of SL : 7.460518, 80.783469

How do I put this dynamically? Pls help

Js fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/madhuri2987/KS4yy/2/

Comment: You should hire a developper. We are not here to do your job...

Comment: No one is here to do anyone's job, if u dont wish to answer then dont,  no one is forcing you to.

Comment: "No one is here to do anyone's job" Sure, have a good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the general idea based on your code. Create an image, check for the country name and change the image's src attribute appropriately.

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    var image = document.createElement('img'),
        country = geoplugin_countryName();
    if ( country === 'India' ) {
        image.src = 'location/of/image/india.jpg'
    } else if ( country === "Sri Lanka" ) {
        image.src = 'location/of/image/sri-lanka.jpg';
    } else {
        image.src = 'location/of/image/default.jpg';
    }
    $('#flag').html( image );
});
```

Full code: http://jsfiddle.net/KS4yy/7/